# AngularJS showing curly braces on second render

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, scope

I am having some difficulty getting the $scope.$apply call to work correctly.

A little background information. I am in the process of transitioning parts of my application to using angular. In order to do this, I am actually injecting data into an Angular factory and firing an event in order to apply the change to the angular scope that has been bootstrapped.

My first load of the module works fine. It outputs the data as I would expect into my template in which I use the ng-each markup. I listen for an event to apply the scope like so:

```
$scope.$on('list:updated', function(event, data){
      $scope.$apply(function(e){
          $scope.list = data;
      });
});
```

The list variable is used within my markup and like I said, this works great the first time around. When navigating away from the angular piece and then revisiting, I get an unrendered template the second time around. So I see things like

```
{{ document.Title }}
```

within my markup intead of the document title like I did on first load. I understand that you can only bootstrap an application once, so I do this to account for that:

```
if (Angular.element(document).scope() === undefined){
    bootstrap = Angular.bootstrap(document, ['listModule']);
}
else{
    bootstrap = Angular.element(document).injector();
}
```

Off of this injector, I get the factory I referenced above, and fire the same list:updated event. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Please let me know what questions I can answer to help get this resolved.

Thanks so much for any help you can provide!

Comment: I suspect that although you are navigating away, the event is not destroyed and your event gets registered a second time, which might be intercepting your call, preventing from the correct scope ever triggering a digest cycle.  A plunkr would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @david-l thanks for responding. I tried to use unbind the event on $scope.$on('$destroy'). Here is some sample code: pastebin.com/mvDRZNzE

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-bind like as -

```
ng-bind='document.Title'
```

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: This produced unwanted effects in the DOM. I started to get [object]object all over the place.